# Why converting empty value to datetime2 is throwing conversion error in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, c#-4.0, datetime2

In C# I get this value for a `datetime2` type:

```
{01/01/0001 00:00:00}
```

Which is because the client is send empty value. In database it throws error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

```
@DateGeneral datetime2 = null
```

in database and procedure.

How do I cover it?

Comment: Best would be to check for empty (string) values and pass them as NULL to the database to get rid of invalid data as early as possible. Maybe add more context for a specific way to treat your input.

Comment: the problem is that it's not coming as a null if sent empty, it's coming 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Comment: Check the input and set `SqlParameter` value to `DBNull.Value` when a dummy value is detected.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `DateTime` is a non-nullable value type. `01/01/0001 00:00:00` is its default value.

`DateGeneral`, on the other hand, is nullable, which makes the `null` value in the database incompatible with what you have in C#.

To fix this problem, use a nullable `DateTime?` data type in your C# program.

Comment: the problem is I cannot make it nullable.

Comment: in c#, i cannot make it nullable.

Comment: because we are following the WSDL provided to us by the client, and there it's not a nullable datetime.

Comment: is there anything i can do at db level?

Comment: @scaryghost Wait, WSDL is on the web service side, not on the DB side, right? You can read from the DB into a nullable type, and then do the conversion when making your WSDL object, for example `wsdlObj.DateGeneral = dbObj.NullableDateGeneral ?? new DateTime()`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this to get date of datetime datetime.value.tosrting()

Answer (score 0):

[.Net datetime maps to DateTime2 data-type of SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data)

**Here are the range of these datatypes.  [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) **

- DateTime range: 1753-01-01 to 9999-12-31
- DateTime2 range: 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31

**To make your solution work, here are the probable fixes:**

1. Make the .net datatype as nullable if your property doesn't need any value.
2. Make the explicit conversion of DataType in .Net (DAL layer)
      map it to DataTime2 
          with EF set Column[TypeName = "datetime2"]
          or in fluent code .HasColumnType("datetime2")
3. Specify the default value (in case of null from .net) to the acceptable range.

Comment: if (GeneralDateI == DateTime.MinValue)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("GeneralDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DBNull.Value;
                            }

Comment: What if the value is explicitly set to DateTime.MinValue in code repo (somewhere). If you're following this approach then there should be some backing field or flag having information whether it's explicitly set value from code or it's the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server `DateTime2`s Date range is wider then that of `DateTime`. If you can't change your C# code then add sanitizing code to your proc, kind of

```
create procedure myproc (.. ,@DateGeneral datetime2 = null, ..)
as
..
-- DATETIME compatiblity check
if (@DateGeneral < DATEFROMPARTS(1753,1,1)) then
   @DateGeneral = null;
```

Comment: I have done this: 
if (GeneralDate == DateTime.MinValue) { cmd.Parameters.Add("GeneralDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DBNull.Value; }

Is this ok?

Comment: Can't say without the context. You may also just skip adding the parameter and Sql server will use default `@DateGeneral datetime2 = null`